# How can I use the OpenLayers module to draw a route between nodes?

Tags: 7, javascript

I have some nodes; I need to build a route using the location assigned to them, and I want to draw it on a map. How can I do that?

Comment: You will need to describe the problem a little more. For example, do you need the route to be on roads? In this case a straight line will not work.

Comment: I believe this is a question for the OpenLayers community. When I talked to them in the past they were very helpful.

Comment: Any update from the question author on this?

Answer (score 1):

[OSM Route](https://www.drupal.org/project/osm_route) looks like it will do exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do easily is to add KML or Geojson layer with one predefined route. This can be requested from [YOURS API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/YOURS). Anything more required more or less development.

Sample KML request: `http://www.yournavigation.org/api/1.0/gosmore.php?format=kml&flat=52.215676&flon=5.963946&tlat=52.2573&tlon=6.1799&v=motorcar&fast=1&layer=mapnik`